# How can the aversion response be explained neurologically?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, behaviorism

If Dopamine and Dopamine D2 receptor is involved in craving, wanting and clinging towards something or [incentive salience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incentive_salience)

> Dopamine is closely associated with reward-seeking behaviors, such as
>   approach, consumption, and addiction.[38] Recent researches suggest
>   that the firing of dopaminergic neurons is a motivational substance as
>   a consequence of reward-anticipation. This hypothesis is based on the
>   evidence that, when a reward is greater than expected, the firing of
>   certain dopaminergic neurons increases, which consequently increases
>   desire or motivation towards the reward ([from dopamine on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine#Learning.2C_reinforcement.2C_and_reward-seeking_behavior) )

What is the opposite mechanism in humans - by which we are experiencing aversion from something?

For example, someone finds something rotten, stinky and covered in white fuzzy mold in a plastic bag. Eww! Gross! Get it away! don't touch it! Keep distance. **What is neurologically responsible for the person's feeling of aversion towards an object like that?**

Are there different pathways to aversion?

For example, would seeing a person who looks like a witch from fairy tales (old, ugly, rotten teeth, lots of warts, body odor) cause the same aversion response as moldy food?

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-do-anatomical-substrates-of-conditioned-taste-aversion-tell-us-about-treat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remembered that [Disgust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disgust#The_neural_basis_of_disgust) is one of the 6 major emotions and there is quite a lot written about it:

> The neural basis of disgust
>
> The scientific attempts to map specific emotions onto underlying
>   neural substrates dates back to the first half of the 20th century.
>   However, it was not until the mid-1990s when it was recognized that
>   six basic emotions, including disgust, were each related to a specific
>   neural structure and therefore considered to be a part of the clinical
>   neurosciences.[23] Functional MRI experiments have revealed that the
>   **anterior insula in the brain** is particularly active when experiencing
>   disgust, when being exposed to offensive tastes, and when viewing
>   facial expressions of disgust.[24] The research has supported that
>   there are independent neural systems in the brain, each handling a
>   specific basic emotion.[4] Specifically, f-MRI studies have provided
>   evidence for the activation of the insula in disgust recognition, as
>   well as visceral changes in disgust reactions such as the feeling of
>   nausea.[4] The importance of disgust recognition and the visceral
>   reaction of "feeling disgusted" is evident when considering the
>   survival of organisms, and the evolutionary benefit of avoiding
>   contamination.[4] [edit]