# What neurological processes occur with 'revulsion'?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, perception, emotion

As the title asks, what neurological processes occur when we feel revulsion?

By revulsion, I mean the involuntary and voluntary physical and psychological responses far stronger than the [aversion discussed in this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-can-the-aversion-response-be-explained-neurologically) to things like, in my case, cockroaches.  I assure you, that I am not referring to 'fear' either, I mean a feeling of loathing towards something.

Comment: A good way to start answering this question would be to find any journal paper at all on how revulsion is different from fear or aversion--that difference needs to be defined before this question can be answered.

Comment: I remember reading that disgust, even if social or visual, had a lot of overlap in activity patterns with the same circuits involved in physiological nausea.

Comment: @KeeganKeplinger that makes sense as that is definitely one of the sensations of 'revulsion'.